# Javascript display onclick with an animation

Tags: javascript, css

I want to animate a simple search form. Before the click event, it is hidden behind my fix nav bar (`margin-top:-47px`). When the user clicks a search button, I want to set the form's margin-top property to 0px so it shows on the page.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6drVH/%C3%A0)

I am using this HTML :

```
<nav>
  <a data-icon="search" class="search-form-toggle"></a>

...
<div class="form search-form">
                <fieldset data-icon="search">
                    <input type="search" placeholder="Search...">
                </fieldset>
            </div>
```

And this CSS :

```
.search-form {
    margin-top: -47px;
}
```

And the following javascript (jQuery) :

```
$('.search-form-toggle').click(function(){
    if($(".search-form").css("margin-top") == "-47px") {
        $(".search-form").animate({margin-top: "0px"}, 1000);
    } else {
        $(".search-form").animate({margin-top: "-47px"}, 1000);
    }
    return false;
});
```

When I click the button, it is not working... I guess it is a Javascript issue?

Plus, can I achieve the same result (nice transition) without using jQuery?

Comment: Yes, you can achieve same result in pure javascript, but with much more code... why would you do it? (ok, benefits from learning are ok, but if this will go on live site, i would use jquery)

Comment: That's because I will only need one jQuery function and I wouldn't want to load the entire library just for that.

Comment: Yes, i understand... well... i guess that someone will reply before me, with good solution... i could try something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer given were really helpful in debugging my code. However, I went with another option when I found animte.css. It is a CSS library that provides multiple animations for divs and others.

I was also using QuoJS, and I didn't want to add jQuery to my loading time, especially since I am developing for mobile devices.

Here is my final code :

JS :

document.querySelector(".search-toggle").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var form = $$(".search-form");

```
if (form.hasClass('display')) {
    form.removeClass('display');
} else {
    form.addClass('display animated flipInX');
}
```

});

CSS :

```
.search-form {
    display:none;
}

.display {
    display:block;
}
```

At first, my div only have the .search-form class, so it is not displayed. I add the .display class with QuoJs with the `addClass()` function.

The transition are very sleek, thanks to animate.css.

Answer (score 2):

The error is in the .animate() it should be:

```
$(".search-form").animate({'margin-top' : '0px'}, 1000);
```

and

```
$(".search-form").animate({margin-top: "-47px"}, 1000);
```

You forgot the quotes around the `margin-top`

here's my working fiddle though make sure you add the ajax file that is attached

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dwzuS/1/)

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. Also, jQuery's doc does not put quotation marks around the css property (http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: hmm... will try and make you a fiddle

Comment: I don't know what an ajax file is, so I guess I haven't ;)

Comment: I pit the ajax file in the fiddle. If you look in external resources then open it in chrome

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working fiddle. You'd forgot to put the quotes.

```
.animate({"margin-top": "XXpx"});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5xxWu/

Comment: Weird... You jsFiddle works, but when I copy the code to my app, it doesn't.

Comment: @JustinD. I've updated the fiddle you provided with your question. It works 

http://jsfiddle.net/6drVH/2/

You'd missed the quotes and you had spaces before and after the hyphens